# Read OPC tag description

Tags: c#, opc

I'm trying to read OPC tag's description with using OPC Foundation libraries, but I can not! I can get many information about tag such as is's name, path, value. Is there any ways to get it's description?

Comment: OPC UA or Classic?

Comment: I'm interesting in Classic OPC DA.

Comment: Probably the person that configured the server never gave it a description. It is very usual.

Comment: I configured those server and I'm sure that all of my tags have a description. And even if they are not have it, I neet to get empty string as a result of function or as a returned value of a property.